# Is it better to tan for 10 minutes without sun protection or the equivalent x amount of minutes with sunscreen?

Tags: sun-exposure, sun-burn, sunscreen-sunblock

For tanning efficiency purposes (i.e. getting as tanned as possible with as little skin damage as possible) is it better to tan for 10 minutes without sunscreen or the equivalent x amount of minutes while wearing sunscreen? Or is there no difference?

Comment: tanning IS skin damage

Comment: Your comment reads entirely different than your question. Rephrasing the question and adding he detail from the comment is done with an [edit].

Comment: An offtopic comment? Perhaps you would like to get something as hot as possible with as little increase in temperature as possible, or lose as much weight as possible with as little change in body mass as possible? What you are asking for is by definition impossible. If you choose not to clarify your question, it will not be answerable.

Comment: I didn't say "there is no difference" I said "tanning without skin damage is impossible." Spending time in the sun without skin damage is possible, but you want to get tanned. That means you want to damage your skin.

Comment: Tanning is not skin damage. Where's your reference for that claim?